# What is the meaning and significance of the word "Sunagimo Umataro" (砂肝うま太郎) in Yuyushiki?

Tags: japanese-language, yuyushiki

In Episode 2 of the anime *Yuyushiki*, Nonohara Yuzuko drew something in response to Hinata Yukari's drawing of a strange penguin-like creature, and wrote down "Sunagimo Umataro" (砂肝うま太郎) on the same page. After some search on the Internet, I now know that "Sunagimo" means "gizzard", which is a digestive organ in chickens and ducks that may be made into food, and "uma" is just a way of saying "delicious". It seems to me that "Sunagimo Umataro" is a name that Yuzuko came up for the creature in the drawing, but I am still not smart enough to connect all the dots and make a meaning out of this. Specifically, I am having trouble figuring out

1. What exactly are those items that appear in Yuzuko's drawing?
2. How is the drawing supposed to be connected to the name "Sunagimo Umataro"?

I apologize if this is question has an obvious answer. (Maybe *Yuyushiki* is just too difficult for me!)

[image: Sunagimo Umataro (Yuyushiki episode 2 screenshot)]

Comment: What items are you referring to in question 1?

Comment: @Ross Ridge: I am referring to the "eyes" and the "mouth" in that drawing right above the word "砂肝うま太郎". Somehow they seemed like separate items to me but I do not know what they are. Or to put it frankly, I do not understand this drawing at all.

Comment: That's just the close-up of the "strange penguin creature"'s face. It has an eye socket, and the mouth looks like a beak.

Comment: You might be confused by the fact the eyes look like the might be a perspective drawing, but if it is then the light source is in a weird spot somewhere between the eyes. The beak on the other hand looks like a petty conventional drawing of a beak. I don't think the words under the face have any other purpose than to give a funny name to the creature, something like Tasty Fat Gizzard Man.

Answer (score 2):

The 'items' in the drawing seem to be part of a close-up view of the strange penguin-looking thing to the right (namely the eyes and the beak).

As for its name, it was probably made up. As you noted, 砂肝{すなぎも} means "gizzard," which is an organ common to most birds (note the drawings bird-like appearance). 太郎{たろう} is a common male name suffix, and [according to a search on jisho.org](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%86%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%20%23names), there are at least two names (both of whose first *kanji* corresponding to 「うま」(*uma*) mean "horse." Leaving it in *kana* may also be, as you noted, a play on 「うまい」(*umai*).

In conclusion, the weird name was most likely crafted to reflect the decidedly weird semblance of the creature in the drawing.

Also of note, the speech bubble translates to something like "don't be so unreasonable," and the text to the left of the image translates to "[the] truth is SCARY."